# feed import on node reference doesn't add language in database

Tags: feeds, nodes, i18n-l10n

I got a XML import witch imports new nodes, in this nodes there is a node reference field. When I run the import I get the message "does not match an existing node" when I look at the nodes they got the node reference, but when you edit the field is empty.

If you look in the database I see that language stays on UND when I change this and update the database it works but when the import runs again its ruined again.

Any solution?

Comment: turned off the translation on the node reference with entity translation. this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off the translation on the node reference with entity translation; this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have run into looks like it may be identified here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1183440.  I walked through this issue queue and was able to get my feed processor to specify the language it was importing.  The [comment #193](https://www.drupal.org/node/1183440#comment-9535591) was particularly useful.  I'll elaborate on his directions a little bit.

For the record, this patch applies only to the feeds module, but you will need to have [Feeds Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_et) installed as well (which you probably already do).

1. `drush dis feeds -y`
2. `rm -rf feeds` - remove feeds directory entirely
3. git-pull the feeds repo and checkout older commit:

   `git clone --branch 7.x-2.x http://git.drupal.org/project/feeds.git`

   `cd feeds`

   `git checkout 006234fc3cc859e4fec0cb261675577efcf389b8`
4. enable all feeds modules that were disabled from step 1:

   `drush en feeds, feeds_ui, feeds_tamper, feeds_tamper_ui, feeds_et, feeds_ex -y`
5. patch feeds:

   `wget https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/feeds-field_translations-1183440-191.patch`

   `git apply < feeds-field_translations-1183440-191.patch`
6. confirm patch by building new feed. you should see a language option under the processor settings.

There is a little bit of work to do on this patch before it can be incorporated in the Feeds trunk, but I'm hopeful it will be in place within a few months.

Comment: I turned off the translation on the node reference with entity translation. Now it works like i want it to be

Comment: wilcocammeraat can you please post the path of the settings.